# How to make shadowed part of background count as background (picture below) with OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, opencv

I am very new to OpenCV(and to StackOverflow). I'm writing a program with OpenCV which takes a picture with an object (i.e. pen(rice, phone) put on paper) and calculates **what percent does the object make of the picture**.

Problem I'm facing with is when I threshold image (tried **adaptive** and **otsu**) photo is a little bit shadow around edges:

[Original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmM5n.png)

[Resulted picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4MTd.png)

And here's my code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread("image.png")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)

th, thresh = cv2.threshold(b, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imwrite("image_bl_wh.png", thresh)
```

Tried to *blur* and *morphology*, but couldn't do it.

How can I make my program count that black parts around the picture as background and is there more better and easier way to do it?

P.S. Sorry for my English grammar mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a programmatic solution but when you do automatic visual inspection it is the first thing you should try: **Improve your set-up.** The image is simply darker around the edges so increasing the brightness when recording the images should help.

If that's not an option you could consider having an empty image for comparison. What you are trying to do is background segmentation and there are better ways than simple color thresholding they do however usually require at least one image of the background or multiple images.

If you want a software only solution you should try an edge detector combined with morphological operators.

Comment: Thank you. Learned how to use gamma correction and that helped me.